# Possible prof error: is this series convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

My sister is taking cal II. Sometimes she calls me for help. This series was created by her professor. He told her it's divergent. I'm finding that it converges, along with two websites that she plugged it into. Can someone identify a problem with my reasoning below?

Question: "Use the Limit Comparison Test to determine whether the following series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot^{-1}(n)}{n^.9}$$

My answer: The series $$\sum \frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$$ converges by the p-test.

Let $$a_k =  \frac{\cot^{-1}(n)}{n^.9}, \quad b_k = \frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$$

then (according to my calculator) $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_k}{b_k} = 0$$

so the series converges by the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which branch of $\cot^{-1}$ - I suppose that is meant to denote $\operatorname{arccot}$ and not $\frac{1}{\cot}$, since the latter would be better written as $\tan$ - one uses.

Absent a specification of the branch, one conventionally uses the branch with values in $(0,\pi)$. And in that case $$\cot^{-1} n \sim n^{-1},$$ so the terms are $\sim n^{-1.9}$. If a different branch is used, $\cot^{-1} n \to k\pi$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ and the series diverges.

Comment: Yes arccot. So to clarify for the branch in $(0,\pi)$ this would be a convergent series? His reasoning involves arccot being approx. zero for large n so i believe that would be the branch hes using.

Comment: Yes, for the branch with values in $(0,\pi)$ the series converges. And we know pretty well what "approximately zero" means here, since $$x\cot x = \frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \cos x$$ has limit $1$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. She refused to bring this up to him without someone other than myself verifying.

Comment: You're welcome.